# php echo result from mysql and datetime selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

MySQL database `Start = "2017-03-29 01:30:00"`

The problem is:

I print the $SQL and search the record in MySQL database, it can search the record. However, I need to debug and test if there is no result, it will be expected to echo "No". But, it always to echo "Yes" no matter I can get the record in MySQL or not.

How can I fixed it.

Main purpose: Get the record if there are and Echo "No" if there don't have record

```
  <?php
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "fyp";
    $tbName = "events";



    $String_start = '2017-03-29 01:28:00';
    $String_end = '2017-03-29 01:32:00';


    $conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dbName);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }



    //$staffID =  $_SESSION['userID'];
    $staff_ID = '15207800';

    $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM `$tbName`
                    WHERE  `start` BETWEEN ('$String_start') AND ('$String_end')";

    echo $sql;
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql query only return fails if there is an issue, for successful execution it returns TRUE even if there is no record. You can achieve with follwing way

```
<?php
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "fyp";
    $tbName = "events";



    $String_start = '2017-03-29 01:28:00';
    $String_end = '2017-03-29 01:32:00';


    $conn = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $dbName);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }



    //$staffID =  $_SESSION['userID'];
    $staff_ID = '15207800';

    $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM `$tbName`
                    WHERE  `start` BETWEEN ('$String_start') AND ('$String_end')";

    echo $sql;
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) that will return total results returned by the query. If total > 0 then results found else no results.

To fetch rows from MySQL result set, use [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

// $result contains result set and will return `TRUE` if query was successfully executed
// and will return `FALSE` only in case of error

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($total > 0)
{
    echo "Yes";
    // Fetch rows from mysql result set
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
```